# Comma separated lists in django templates

Tags: python, django, list, django-templates

If `fruits` is the list `['apples', 'oranges', 'pears']`,

is there a quick way using django template tags to produce "apples, oranges, and pears"?

I know it's not difficult to do this using a loop and `{% if counter.last %}` statements, but because I'm going to use this repeatedly I think I'm going to have to learn how to write custom <del>tags</del> filters, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it's already been done.

As an extension, my attempts to drop the [Oxford Comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) (ie return "apples, oranges and pears") are even messier.

Comment: Why aren't you using the existing join template tag?

Comment: @S.Lott: I didn't spot the join template tag when I looked through the list on the docs page. Oops. Having said that, the next stage is to wrap each item in the list in a hyperlink, for which I think I'll need to write a filter.

Comment: If you're using links to your Django URL's, you'll need to use the `{% url %}` tag.  The `{% for %}` loop suddenly looks much more appealing.  "Repeatedly" often means your templates need to `{% include %}` common features.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the filter I wrote to solve my problem (it doesn't include the Oxford comma)

```
def join_with_commas(obj_list):
    """Takes a list of objects and returns their string representations,
    separated by commas and with 'and' between the penultimate and final items
    For example, for a list of fruit objects:
    [<Fruit: apples>, <Fruit: oranges>, <Fruit: pears>] -> 'apples, oranges and pears'
    """
    if not obj_list:
        return ""
    l=len(obj_list)
    if l==1:
        return u"%s" % obj_list[0]
    else:    
        return ", ".join(str(obj) for obj in obj_list[:l-1]) \
                + " and " + str(obj_list[l-1])
```

To use it in the template: `{{ fruits|join_with_commas }}`

Answer (score 158):

First choice: use the existing join template tag.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join

Here's their example

```
{{ value|join:" // " }}
```

Second choice: do it in the view.

```
fruits_text = ", ".join( fruits )
```

Provide `fruits_text` to the template for rendering.

Comment: I might require other lists (eg `vegetables_text`), and I may use these lists in lots of views, so I'd rather have a solution that only requires me to alter the templates. One of the reasons I was thinking about writing a custom tag is that I can use Python - `join` is definitely more elegant than for loops.

Comment: This also doesn't insert the final "and".

Comment: Is there any best practice as to whether to do this in the template or in the view?

Comment: What if each object in the list is a clickable link?

Answer (score 77):

Here's a super simple solution.  Put this code into comma.html:

```
{% if not forloop.last %}{% ifequal forloop.revcounter 2 %} and {% else %}, {% endifequal %}{% else %}{% endif %}
```

And now wherever you'd put the comma, include "comma.html" instead:

```
{% for cat in cats %}
Kitty {{cat.name}}{% include "comma.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Update: @user3748764 gives us a slightly more compact version, without the deprecated ifequal syntax:

```
{% if not forloop.first %}{% if forloop.last %} and {% else %}, {% endif %}{% endif %}
```

Note that it should be used before the element, not after.

Comment: the best solution if you need to join more than the strings in an array

Comment: All you need to do to add the [Oxford comma](http://grammar.wikia.com/wiki/Oxford_comma) is to replace `and` with `, and`.

Comment: A slightly more compact version without the deprecated ifequal syntax.
`{% if not forloop.first %}{% if forloop.last %} and {% else %}, {% endif %}{% endif %}`
Note that it should be used before the element, not after.

Comment: What if each object in the list is a clickable object?

Answer (score 42):

On the Django template this all you need to do for establishing a comma after each fruit. The comma will stop once its reached the last fruit.

```
{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
```

Comment: Very clean & easy solution.

Answer (score 35):

I would suggest a custom django templating *filter* rather than a custom *tag* -- filter is handier and simpler (where appropriate, like here). `{{ fruits | joinby:", " }}` looks like what I'd want to have for the purpose... with a custom `joinby` filter:

```
def joinby(value, arg):
    return arg.join(value)
```

which as you see is simplicity itself!

Comment: I wasn't aware of the distinction between tags and filters. Whereas the custom tags seem slightly daunting when I look at the documentation, filters appear to be simpler, and exactly what I need in this case. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't insert the final "and".

Comment: @Meekohi, so `return arg.join(value[:-1]) + ' and ' + value[-1]` (for AP style, i.e, no comma before `and`; for "Oxford comma" style, add a `+ arg` right before the ` + 'and'`). Me, I prefer the strength of the asyndeton, per http://literarydevices.net/asyndeton/ . And none of this fine debate on English style belongs on StackOverflow anyway -- take it to english.stackexchange.com!-)

Comment: +1 for coming back to a 6 year old question to answer a 3 year old comment, but what does your filter do when there is only one item in the array? :) Making things human readable is not so easy it seems.

Comment: My original asyndeton filter works fine; the new ones inserting `'and'` are coded in the above comment to unconditionally insert `'and'`. All it takes to behave differently for very short `value` is to code `[[as above] if len(value)>1 else value`. And BTW asyndeton is HIGHLY human readable -- Aristotle, Shakespeare, Joyce (among many others of course) all used it effectively, and my preference for it is rooted in my being a poet, first and foremost.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a '.' on the end of Michael Matthew Toomim's answer, then use:

```
{% if not forloop.last %}{% ifequal forloop.revcounter 2 %} and {% else %}, {% endifequal %}{% else %}{% endif %}{% if forloop.last %}.{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

All of the answers here fail one or more of the following:

- They rewrite something (poorly!) that's in the standard template library (ack, top answer!)
- They don't use `and` for the last item.
- They lack a serial (oxford) comma.
- They use negative indexing, which won't work for django querysets.
- They don't usually handle string sanitation properly.

Here's my entry into this canon. First, the tests:

```
class TestTextFilters(TestCase):

    def test_oxford_zero_items(self):
        self.assertEqual(oxford_comma([]), '')

    def test_oxford_one_item(self):
        self.assertEqual(oxford_comma(['a']), 'a')

    def test_oxford_two_items(self):
        self.assertEqual(oxford_comma(['a', 'b']), 'a and b')

    def test_oxford_three_items(self):
        self.assertEqual(oxford_comma(['a', 'b', 'c']), 'a, b, and c')
```

And now the code. Yes, it gets a bit messy, but you'll see that it *doesn't* use negative indexing:

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@register.filter(is_safe=True, needs_autoescape=True)
def oxford_comma(l, autoescape=True):
    """Join together items in a list, separating them with commas or ', and'"""
    l = map(force_text, l)
    if autoescape:
        l = map(conditional_escape, l)

    num_items = len(l)
    if num_items == 0:
        s = ''
    elif num_items == 1:
        s = l[0]
    elif num_items == 2:
        s = l[0] + ' and ' + l[1]
    elif num_items > 2:
        for i, item in enumerate(l):
            if i == 0:
                # First item
                s = item
            elif i == (num_items - 1):
                # Last item.
                s += ', and ' + item
            else:
                # Items in the middle
                s += ', ' + item

    return mark_safe(s)
```

You can use this in a django template with:

```
{% load my_filters %}
{{ items|oxford_comma }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use `', '.join(['apples', 'oranges', 'pears'])` before sending it to the template as a context data.

UPDATE:

```
data = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears']
print(', '.join(data[0:-1]) + ' and ' + data[-1])
```

You will get `apples, oranges and pears` output.

Comment: That gives `"apples, oranges, pears"`. The required output is `"apples, oranges, and pears"`.

Comment: Oh, looks like I missed it. I've updated my answer. Please have a look. @Alasdair

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't have support for this out-of-the-box. You can define a custom filter for this:

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def join_and(value):
    """Given a list of strings, format them with commas and spaces, but
    with 'and' at the end.

    >>> join_and(['apples', 'oranges', 'pears'])
    "apples, oranges, and pears"

    """
    # convert numbers to strings
    value = [str(item) for item in value]

    if len(value) == 1:
        return value[0]

    # join all but the last element
    all_but_last = ", ".join(value[:-1])
    return "%s, and %s" % (all_but_last, value[-1])
```

However, if you want to deal with something more complex than just lists of strings, you'll have to use an explicit `{% for x in y %}` loop in your template.

Answer (score 1):

If you like one-liners:

```
@register.filter
def lineup(ls): return ', '.join(ls[:-1])+' and '+ls[-1] if len(ls)>1 else ls[0]
```

and then in the template:

```
{{ fruits|lineup }}
```

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't available as a template tag, there is an Django function, no other answer seems to have mentioned, that already does this [get_text_list](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5bfb3cbf49e2b9701e7c42989e14a72374adb6bd/django/utils/text.py#L255). This should be very easy to wrap with a template filter to make available in templates. Something like:

```
@register.filter
def text_list(value, conjunction):
    return get_text_list(value, conjunction)
```

`{{ items | text_list:"and" }}`

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution might be:

```py
@register.filter
def comma_list(p_values: Iterable[str]) -> List[str]:
    values = list(p_values)
    if len(values) > 1:
        values[-1] = u'and %s' % values[-1]
    if len(values) > 2:
        return u', '.join(values)
    return u' '.join(values)
```