# Django manytomany field filter list

Tags: django

I am printing a list of beers matching some filters, and the bars where each is on tap. These are in a manytomany relationship. I need to filter this list of bars to only show those in a given state.

I can achieve this using if statements in the template, but then am unable to format the list to use commas with an 'and' before the final item (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3649002/6180992), as I do not know the length of the list.

I have thought of three ways this might be possible, but cannot get any to work:

- filtering the bars related field as well as the beers in the views
- assembling the list in the template before looping through again to print it
- filtering the bars related field in the template

Here are the relevant sections of code:

**models.py**

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='FinshnPig')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='NY')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bar
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('bar','region')


class Tap(models.Model):
    bar = models.ManyToManyField(Bar,default='FinshnPig')
    brewery = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    beer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='NY')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.beer
```

**views.py**

```
f = TapFilter(request.GET, queryset=Tap.objects.filter(state="VIC"))
```

**template:**

```
{% for tap in filter %}
  <li>
  <b>{{ tap.beer }}</b>
  <em>{{ tap.brewery }}</em>
  @{% for bar in tap.bar.all %}{% if bar.state == "VIC" %}{{ bar.bar }}</b>{% endif %}{% include "taplists/comma.html" %}{% endfor %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) for querying only the related bars before sending it to template, like so:

```
prefetch =  Prefetch(
    'bar', 
    queryset=Bar.objects.filter(state=CHOSEN_STATE),
    to_attr='selected_states'
)
filter = Tap.objects.filter(state=CHOSEN_STATE).prefetch_related(prefetch)
```

Now inside your template use the custom attribute you assigned:

```
{% for tap in filter %}
   # Now selected_bars only contains the bars in the state you want
   {% for bar in tap.selected_bars.all %}
   ...
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Additional info on Django docs for [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Note: Using prefetch for `ManyToMany` relations will also increase the performance, as there won't be as many database lookups.

Comment: Thank you! I just had to remove the .all in the template, but otherwise this works terrifically!